# unable to resolve class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder

Tags: android, android-studio

I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufXXX.png) error after updating android studio:

```
Error:Cause: startup failed:
initialization script 'C:\Users\sunny\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle': 17: unable to resolve class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
 @ line 17, column 1.
   import org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
```

Comment: You need to import `ExtraModelBuilder`

Comment: But how to do that ? In ijinit.gradle ExtraModelBuilder is already imported, i saw when opened that file.

Comment: what is your gradle version?

Comment: it is 2.3.3  . this error occurred 2 days ago when i updated android studio and its components. I think its a problem with ijinit.gradle, is there any way to update it or i need to do something else. please help me

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: If it works please accept my answer as correct

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**CHANGING GRADLE TO LATEST VERSION FIXED THIS PROBLEM**

In this case it was changing from 3.3 to 4.0

**If you want to see what the latest Gradle version is, have a look [here](https://gradle.org/releases/).**

---

Change your gradle version in project setting: 
If you are using mac - click File->Project structure,then change gradle version (Windows will be similar),here:

[image]

And check your build.gradle of project,change dependency of gradle,like this:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath     
    'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    }
}
```

If none of the above works you can roll back to previous android studio version to a stable release:

[Select the version you want here](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary)

Comment: my gradle version is 3.3 and plugin version is 2.3.3 and classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2' . Now what i need to change. i also attach ijinit.gradle image above in my question, you can check and there is also one ijinit1.gradle in which only null....null is written. please solve this mistry

Comment: Both are not working bro. i dont know what to do now

Comment: in gradle version which version i need to write.

Comment: i dont know but i want remove this error at any how

Comment: when i change gradle version,then error came,        Error:(1, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3. Current version is 2.2.1.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
<a href="fixGradleVersionInWrapper">Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project</a><br><a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a>

Comment: my android studio is 2.3.3 . so how to solve it now bro

Comment: ok, but i also tried that, same error occurs and iam using stable channel.

Comment: hey buddy, i did it. I changed gradle version from 3.3 to 4.0 and boooom. now error goes and it works fine. but it was you who gave told me to play with gradle version. i got this idea when in error i saw that minumum version is 3.3, then i searched for latest version and change its version. thanks again

Comment: hi brook, error goes after changing version to 4.0 , but when i create new project every time it shows the same error, and then  i need to change version to 4.0 in every  new project. what it its cause? i think there may be some other problem. can you help me please

Comment: My gradle version is  3.2.0 and plugin is 4.6, Can any one say what to do? same error appears

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when using 2023.2.1 version android studio to build a project need gradle 8.4 and AGP version 4.2.0

In my case, I found the gradle plugin jar in folder `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2023.2\plugins\gradle\lib` is little different than `<Android Studio installed folder>\plugins\gradle\lib`, don't know why, so I copy the jars in Android Studio folder to replace the appdata forlder, then error gones.

Also found this error everytime I start IDE:
[image]

So everytime I need replace the correct lib to appdata folder to resolve this issue, hope I could find why.