# Gradle build fails with "unable to resolve class: ExtraModelBuilder"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I would like to start programming an android application. I am following a tutorial etc. and when in the background gradle tries to build the project I get an error:

```
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 153 ms
 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle' line: 4
 
* What went wrong:
Could not compile initialization script 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  initialization script 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle': 4: unable to resolve class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
   @ line 4, column 1.
     import org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
     ^
 
  1 error
```

Full exception details: https://pastebin.com/jqQkycLc

I have Android Studio version 2021.3.1 (the latest) and I just started my project (I just added strings in strings.xml)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should post your error message in your question, not on another site (people won't bother looking!) There's a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44890994/13598222 (make sure you've updated Gradle, the tutorial might be relying on another version. More info about that stuff here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Comment: This isn't "guess the error message" here; please provide `ijinit.gradle`.

Comment: here it is @MartinZeitler : 
[link](https://pastebin.com/r32QrUUY)

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer appears to be: upgrade to Gradle 7.2, as it is suggested [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-245303).